# Adding two strings mathematically?

Tags: c++, string, int, converters

i was looking around the forums and i still couldnt find my answer to my problem.
I got two strings, that are just really an array of numbers. for example(i just choose random numbers

```
    string input1="12345678909876543212";
    string input2="12345";
```

I want to add these two string together but act them like there integers.
My goal is creating a class where i can add bigger numbers than (long long int) so it can exceed the largest long long int variable.

So i revese the string with no problem, so now there

```
  input1="21234567890987654321" 
  input2="54321"
```

then i tried adding, let's say input1[0]+input2[0] (2+5) to a new string lets call it newString[0] where that would equal (7); but i cant find a good way to temporally convert the current number in the string so i can add it to the new string? can anyone help. I get sick and tired of atoi,stof,stod. they don't seem to work at all for me.
Any way i can make this function work.
 I don't care about making the class yet, i just care about finding a way to add those two strings mathematically but still maintaining the newString's string format. Thank you for whoever can figure this out for me

Comment: Use an existing bignum library, for example: boost multiprecision. See this wikipedia article for a general discussion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: well i want to create my own thats the thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so, assuming your only problem is with the logic, not the class design thing, I came up with this logic

- fill up the inputs with 0s, checking the lengths, match the lengths
- add like normal addition, keeping track of carry
- finally remove leading zeros from result

So using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a lambda function on reverse iterators :-

```
char carry = 0;

std::transform(input1.rbegin(),input1.rend(),input2.rbegin(),
              result.rbegin(),[&carry]( char x,  char y){
    char z = (x-'0')+(y-'0') + carry;
    if (z > 9)
    {
        carry = 1;
        z -= 10;
    }
    else
    {
        carry = 0;
    }
    return z + '0';
});

//And finally the last carry
result[0] = carry + '0';

//Remove the leading zero
n = result.find_first_not_of("0");
if (n != string::npos)
{
    result = result.substr(n);
}
```

See [***Here***](http://ideone.com/o7wLTt)

**Edit** *"Can you comment on what your doing here"*

```
                +--------+--------------+------------+-------> Reverse Iterator
                |        |              |            |
std::transform( | input1.rbegin(), input1.rend(),input2.rbegin(),
               result.rbegin(), [&carry]( char x,  char y){
               //This starts a lambda function
    char z = (x-'0')+(y-'0') + carry; // x,y have ASCII value of each digit
    // Substracr ASCII of 0 i.e. 48 to get the "original" number
    // Add them up
    if (z > 9) //If result greater than 9, you have a carry
    {
        carry = 1; // store carry for proceeding sums
        z -= 10; // Obviously 
    }
    else
    {
        carry = 0; //Else no carry was generated
    }
    return z + '0'; // Now you have "correct" number, make it a char, add 48
});
```

`std::transform` is present in header `<algorithm>`, see the ideone posted link.

Comment: Can you comment on what your doing here... I'm not sure what's going on all the way? Thank you

Comment: And std::transform? I can't seem to find it.. I'm using visual studio

Comment: @Juan updated answer, if you still don't get it, I suggest you to get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232)

Answer (score 3):

Here's A Solution for adding two numbers represented as strings .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string add(string a, string b)
{
   int al=a.size()-1;
   int bl=b.size()-1;

   int carry=0;
   string result="";

   while(al>=0 && bl>=0)
    {
    int temp = (int)(a[al] - '0') + (int)(b[bl] - '0') + carry ;
    carry = 0;
    if(temp > 9 )
    {
        carry=1;
        temp=temp-10;
    }

    result+=char(temp + '0');
    al--;
    bl--;
    }

   while(al>=0)
    {
        int temp = (int)(a[al] - '0') + carry ;
        carry = 0;
        if(temp>9)
        {
            carry=1;
            temp=temp%10;
        }

        result+=char(temp + '0');
        al--;
    }

   while(bl>=0)
    {
        int temp = (int)(b[bl] - '0') + carry ;
        carry = 0;
        if(temp>9)
        {
            carry=1;
            temp=temp%10;
        }

        result+=char(temp + '0');
        bl--;
    }

if(carry)
    result+="1";

string addition="";

for(int i=result.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
    addition+=result[i];   // reversing the answer

return addition;
}

string trim(string a)   // for removing leading 0s
{
   string res="";
   int i=0;

   while(a[i]=='0')
      i++;

   for(;i<a.size();i++)
    res+=a[i];

   return res;
}


int main()
{
    string a;
    string b;

    cin>>a>>b;

    cout<<trim(add(a,b))<<endl;
}
```

Comment: A small bug in the code. After adding carry to the "temp" set carry = 0 (in the three loop) as the carry I already added to the resulting added number.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a very femilier with C++ but cant we do this?

```
   int i = stoi( input1[0]); 
     int j = stoi( input2[0]);
     int x = i+j;
```

Please note this can be done in  C++11  Please refer [[1]](http://tombarta.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/specializing-atoi/) and [2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) as well

Comment: the compliler complains about that. I honestly don't know what.

Comment: Are you using C++11? can you please try this  as well std::string s = "21234567890987654321";
int i = std::stoi(s);

Comment: for(i=0; 0<= 20; i++)
 {
 
  int x,y;
  x=std::stoi(input1[i]);


 
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a char to an int by subtracting '0' from it:

```
char sumdigit = (input1[0]-'0') + (input2[0]-'0') + '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

`atoi()` would be a better to go, as far as converting `input[0]` to an int:

```
int temp = atoi(input.substr(0,1).c_str());
```

then use stringstream to convert back to string:

```
stringstream convert;
convert << temp;
string newString = convert.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, but this is so far from sensible that it is not even funny.

GCC 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x dumb-big-num.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

// dumb big num
// unsigned integer
class DBN {
public:
  DBN() : num("0") {}

  explicit DBN(const std::string& s) : num(s) {
    for (const auto& c : num) {
      if (!std::isdigit(c)) { throw std::invalid_argument("DBN::DBN"); } }
    std::reverse(std::begin(num), std::end(num)); }

  DBN operator+(const DBN& rhs) const {
    DBN tmp(*this);
    return tmp += rhs; }

  DBN& operator+=(const DBN& rhs) {
    std::string r;
    const int m = std::min(num.size(), rhs.num.size());
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      int s = (num[i] - '0') + (rhs.num[i] - '0') + c;
      c = s / 10;
      s %= 10;
      r += static_cast<char>('0' + s); }
    const std::string& ref = num.size() < rhs.num.size() ? rhs.num : num;
    for (int i = m; i < ref.size(); ++i) {
      int s = (ref[i] - '0') + c;
      c = s / 10;
      s %= 10;
      r += static_cast<char>('0' + s); }
    if (0 < c) { r += '1'; }
    num = r;
    return *this; }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DBN& rhs);
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& os, DBN& rhs);

private:
  std::string num;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DBN& rhs) {
  std::string s(rhs.num);
  std::reverse(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
  return os << s;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, DBN& rhs) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  char c;
  while (is && std::isspace(is.peek())) { is.ignore(); }
  while (is) {
    if (!std::isdigit(is.peek())) { break; }
    is >> c;
    ss << c; }
  DBN n(ss.str());
  rhs = n;
  return is;
}

int main() {
  DBN a, b, t;
  while (std::cin >> a >> b) {
    std::cout << a + b << "\n";
    (t += a) += b;
  }
  std::cout << t << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a simple C++ code

```
string Sum(string a, string b)
{
    if(a.size() < b.size())
        swap(a, b);

    int j = a.size()-1;
    for(int i=b.size()-1; i>=0; i--, j--)
        a[j]+=(b[i]-'0');

    for(int i=a.size()-1; i>0; i--)
        if(a[i] > '9')
        {
            int d = a[i]-'0';
            a[i-1] = ((a[i-1]-'0') + d/10) + '0';
            a[i] = (d%10)+'0';
        }
    if(a[0] > '9')
    {
        string k;
        k+=a[0];
        a[0] = ((a[0]-'0')%10)+'0';
        k[0] = ((k[0]-'0')/10)+'0';
        a = k+a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cited from [C - Adding the numbers in 2 strings together if a different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660677/c-adding-the-numbers-in-2-strings-together-if-a-different-length/16666691#16666691)
answer, I write a more readable code：

```
void str_reverse(char *beg, char *end){
    if(!beg || !end)return;
    char cTmp;
    while(beg < end){
        cTmp = *beg;
        *beg++ = *end;
        *end-- = cTmp;
    }
}

#define c2d(c) (c - '0')
#define d2c(d) (d + '0')
void str_add(const char* s1, const char* s2, char* s_ret){
    int s1_len = strlen(s1);
    int s2_len = strlen(s2);

    int max_len = s1_len;
    int min_len = s2_len;
    const char *ps_max = s1;
    const char *ps_min = s2;

    if(s2_len > s1_len){
        ps_min = s1;min_len = s1_len;
        ps_max = s2;max_len = s2_len;
    }

    int carry = 0;
    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = max_len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        // this wrong-prone
        int idx = (i - max_len + min_len) >=0 ? (i - max_len + min_len) : -1;
        int sum = c2d(ps_max[i]) + (idx >=0  ? c2d(ps_min[idx]) : 0) + carry;

        carry = sum / 10;
        sum = sum % 10;

        s_ret[j++] = d2c(sum);
    }

    if(carry)s_ret[j] = '1';
    str_reverse(s_ret, s_ret + strlen(s_ret) - 1);
}
```

test code as below:

```
void test_str_str_add(){
    char s1[] = "123";
    char s2[] = "456";
    char s3[10] = {'\0'};

    str_add(s1, s2, s3);
    std::cout<<s3<<std::endl;

    char s4[] = "456789";
    char s5[10] = {'\0'};
    str_add(s1, s4, s5);
    std::cout<<s5<<std::endl;

    char s7[] = "99999";
    char s8[] = "21";
    char s9[10] = {'\0'};
    str_add(s7, s8, s9);
    std::cout<<s9<<std::endl;
}
```

output:

579

456912

100020