# Turn a 2D array into a 1D array which has the sum of the values in the 2D array as its elements

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, sum

The question is confusing and possibly not worded correctly. Let me clarify. If we have a 2-dimensional array `vector<vector<int>> A = {{i, j, k}, {x, y, z}}`. What is the fastest way to find a 1-dimensional array C such that that `vector<int> C = {i + x, j + y, k + z}`?

Additionally, in the problem I'm working on, I will have to carry numbers ie if we have a sum of 25, 2 will have to be carried into the next sum and 5 will remain as the current sum.

I've tried to use a for loop. However, it's very tedious and quite slow for large arrays.

Hopefully, there are some helpful functions out there?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Edited.

Comment: So just add the elements of each array and place them into a new 1 dim array?

Comment: Yea... I may have overcomplicated things

Comment: Is each number actually just a single digit as you mention carry...  Or do you mean carry when <int> overflows?

Comment: Single-digit. Just think of long-addition. That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah - that's a little different.  By any chance are the digits actually characters in the range of '0' through '9'?  Or literally just 0-9 stored in a very large integer space?

Comment: Dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262193/adding-two-strings-mathematically  Just replace `string` with `vector`.  They're basically the same thing

Comment: Might be a perfect dupe - was just trying to narrow it down first :)

Comment: Huh! It really is perfect! Thanks for finding this anyways